# jquery slide speed is not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have two `divs` left and right am trying to slide left div and whenever the left div hides the right div width becomes 100%. this condition is working fine ,but when I apply speed slow or fast its not working.

My code so far,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   // jQuery methods go here...
          $("#show").hide();
          $("#clickme").show();
});

$(document).ready(function(){

     $("#clickme").click(function(){       
        $("#left").hide();
        $("#right").css("width", "100%");
       // $("#right").slide({ direction: "left"  }, "slow");
        $("#clickme").hide();
        $("#show").show();

    });
    $("#show").click(function(){   
        $("#right").css("width", "80%");
        $("#left").css("display", "block");
        $("#show").hide();
        $("#clickme").show();
        $("#left").show( "slide", { direction: "left"  }, 5000  );  

    });
});
```

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML/CSS code.

Comment: Why using two time document.ready ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$("#right").animate({width:"100%", left: 100%}, "slow");`

Comment: its changing in right side but can i make it in left side

Comment: look at my post. I added a left property. Try with 100% or 0px or any other value

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to know that slide effects are part of jQueryUI . So,please include its CDN links or download a local copy of it.
Include this code in your HTML file(Ignore if you already have it):

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And the only change in your script is ( That commented line ) :

```
$('#right').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 3000);
```

And as far as I know you must use Miliseconds  for manipulating the speed of the sliding effect.